# Ajax não popula select na segunda requisição

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, tenho algumas requisições ajax na minha página que populam um `select` corretamente, porém, preciso que faça novamente num modal de atualização, mas a mesma requisição ajax não retorna nada.

Esse é o código da primeira requisição:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Categoria</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria" required>
        <option>--- Selecione ---</option>
        <?php
        $nivel = 0;
        $select = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE nivel = '$nivel'";
        $result_select = $conn->query($select);
        while ($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select)):
            echo '<option value="' . $col['id'] . '">' . $col['nome'] . '</option>';
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sub Categoria1</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="sub_categoria1" name="sub_categoria">
        <option>--- Selecione ---</option>

        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('jquery', '1.3');
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#categoria').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val()) {

                        $.getJSON('functions/pega_categoria.php?search=', {
                            id: $(this).val(),
                            ajax: 'true'
                        }, function (j) {
                            var options = '<option value=""></option>';
                            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                                options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';

                            }
                            $('#sub_categoria1').html(options);


                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#sub_categoria1').html('<option value="">--- Selecione ---</option>');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    </select>
</div>
```

Essa primeira funciona corretamente, porém, a segunda não.
Essa é a segunda vez que eu requisito.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Categoria</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoriaModal" required>
                                    <option>--- Selecione ---</option>
                                    <?php
                                    $nivel1 = 0;
                                    $select1 = "SELECT * FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE nivel = '$nivel1'";
                                    $result_select1 = $conn->query($select1);
                                    while ($col1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select1)):
                                        echo '<option value="' . $col1['id'] . '">' . $col1['nome'] . '</option>';
                                    endwhile;
                                    ?>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sub Categoria1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select class="form-control" id="sub_categoria1Modal" name="sub_categoria">
                                    <option>--- Selecione ---</option>

                                    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        google.load('jquery', '1.3');
                                    </script>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function () {
                                            $('#categoriaModal').change(function () {
                                                if ($(this).val()) {

                                                    $.getJSON('functions/pega_categoria.php?search=', {
                                                        id: $(this).val(),
                                                        ajax: 'true'
                                                    }, function (j) {
                                                        var options = '<option value=""></option>';
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                                                            options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';

                                                        }
                                                        $('#sub_categoria1Modal').html(options);


                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    $('#sub_categoria1Modal').html('<option value="">--- Selecione ---</option>');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Esse é o php:

```
<?php include("conexao.php");

$id_cat_selecionada = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sub_categoria = array();

$sql = "SELECT id,nome FROM categoria_recursiva WHERE id_pai=$id_cat_selecionada";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
while ( $col_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    $sub[] = array(
        'id'    => $col_cat['id'],
        'nome'  => $col_cat['nome'],
    );


}

echo( json_encode( $sub ) );
?>
```

Comment: Fiz um teste com seu código, ignorando apenas o SQL e retornando um array estático. Funcionou perfeitamente. Aconselho você usar um try catch para capturar qualquer tipo de erro e/ou olhar os logs do apache/nginx.

Comment: Olá Patrick, todas as requisições ajax funcionaram? aqui não funciona de jeito nenhum

Comment: eu não entendo muito sobre isso que vc falou, poderia dar uma força?

Answer (score 1):

Por que suas tag script está dentro da tag Select?

Quando você faz

`$('#sub_categoria1').html('TEXTO');` ou `$('#sub_categoria1Modal').html('TEXTO');`

Vocês está apagando todo o seu script, por isso da segunda vez ele não funciona.

Comment: não entendi, a primeira vez funciona normalmente, mas na segunda eu começo ele inteiro novamente, não entendi o que disse

Comment: O que ele quis dizer @CaioBrandão é que seu "script" está dentro do componente `<select>`. O correto é você colocar ele no final da página, antes de fechar o `</body>`. Com isso, evita do seu script ser apagado pela função `html()`.

Comment: Excelente observação Rafael! Não tinha nem me atentado a isso.

Comment: Remova as tags SCRIPT de dentro do SELECT, que provavelmente funcionará.

Veja que você mesmo está tendo que reinserir o primeiro <option> ```$('#sub_categoria1').html('<option value="">--- Selecione ---</option>'); ``` pois ele também está sendo apagado.

Comment: galera, vou pedir desculpas mas eu realmente não entendi, devo remover toda a função do select? e quanto ao html que precisa retornar pro select? retirei a função inteira e desci o código e não funcionou

Comment: O fato da tag **script** estar dentro da tag **select**, não quer dizer que o retorno do AJAX será inserido no **select**, o que faz isso é essa linha: ``` $('#sub_categoria1Modal').html(options); ```
Onde 
```$('#sub_categoria1Modal') ``` - Retorna o elemento de ID '#sub_categoria1Modal'
```.html(options); ``` - insere a string no elemento

Comment: entendi Rafael, tentei isso, e não funcionou